# Can not connect to Virtualbox Server from remote desktop

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have installed Windows Server 2019 on Virtualbox inside my local server.
In Virtualbox Network setting I have set Bridged card. In Windows Server, I have set static IP.
I can see this IP on Ip lists. When I am trying to connect to this server from the remote desktop I can not. I have also set port forwarding on my router so I could have access outside my network. It does not work. Can you help me and advice what to do because I am out of ideas?

Comment: Is RDP enabled in the server? Is the RDP port open in the Windows Firewall?

Comment: Windows Server starts by default with all services disabled in firewall. Make sure the firewall port is open and the allow rule is not limited to the IP range of your local network (also a default setting of Windows server).

Comment: I have port RDP on Windows Server 2019 OPEN: 3389.
There is no limited, I have set Edge Traversal to allow  and still it does not want to connect